# Problem related with analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I was thinking about the following problem:

Let $$S=\{0\}\cup \{ \frac{1}{4n+1}:n=1,2,3,4,\dots\}$$ Then what is the total number of analytic function which vanish only on $S$?

I was trying to use the fact that zeros of analytic functions are isolated. But I could not progress further. Am I going in the right direction? Please help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right lines: is $0$ isolated in the set $\{ 0 \} \cup \left\{ \dfrac{1}{4n+1}\, :\, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$?

Below is a hint: hover your mouse over the grey box to see it.

> Given $\varepsilon > 0$, can you find an $n$ such that $\dfrac{1}{4n+1} < \varepsilon$?

Comment: No,sir.I do not think that here in the set $0$ is an isolated point. Here, we can choose $n$ to be arbitrarily large so that any nbd. of ${0}$ will contain points from the set ${1/(4n+1): n \in \mathbb N}$. Am i right?

Comment: Yup. So how many analytic functions vanish on the given set (and not elsewhere)?

Comment: Sir, i think i have got your point. Since zeros of analytic functions are isolated and the set does not contain any isolated zero  ,hence we can conclude that the number of analytic functions vanish on the given set (and not elsewhere) is ZERO. Am i right?

Comment: That's right :) Except it's wrong to say it doesn't contain *any* isolated zeros: it contains infinitely many! But the point is that it *does* contain a zero which isn't isolated.

Comment: No... you were right in saying that there are no analytic functions vanishing on $S$. But this is because $S$ contains *at least one* non-isolated zero.

Comment: Sorry sir.After posting my previous comment, I realized that i went wrong in my argument. So, i deleted my earlier comment which may mislead me( or even others who will go through it in future).I have got it,now. Thanks a lot for your time.